# p5ライブラリの関数が未定義になる原因が知りたい。

Tags: javascript

提示コードの`///`コメント部内部のコードですがこのコードで以下のエラーが発生します。これはなぜでしょうか？`createContext()`関数の後に`let game = Game();`というように定義しているのですが原因がわかりません。

参考サイト: [circle() is not definded on web editor · Issue #3512 · processing/p5.js · GitHub](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/3512)
p5ライブラリ: https://p5js.org/

###### エラーコード

```
Game.js:94 Uncaught ReferenceError: circle is not defined
    at Puyo.Renderer (Game.js:94:9)
    at Game.Renderer (Game.js:121:19)
    at draw (Main.js:20:10)
    at p5.redraw (p5.js:14100:7)
    at p5.<anonymous> (p5.js:9144:12)
    at p5.<anonymous> (p5.js:9040:12)
    at new p5 (p5.js:9320:12)
    at _globalInit (p5.js:5602:7)
```

###### Game.js

```
"use strict"

const CELL_SIZE = 25;   //ぷよサイズ


// ################################################################
// # 操作 クラス
// ################################################################
class Control
{

    constructor()
    {
        this.position = new Vector(0,0);
    }

    Update()
    {

        if(keyIsDown(UP_ARROW))
        {
            
        }
        else if(keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW))
        {
            this.position.x += -CELL_SIZE;
        }
        else if(keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW))
        {
            this.position.x += CELL_SIZE;
        }
    }


    getPosition()
    {
        return this.position;
    }

}

// ################################################################
// # ぷよ クラス
// ################################################################
class Puyo
{
    
    getColor(rand)
    {


    }

    constructor()
    {        
        this.rand = random(5);
        
        this.position = new Vector(0,0);        //座標
    }

    setPosition(pos)
    {
        this.position = pos;
    }



    Renderer() 
    {
        
        if(this.rand == 0)
        {
            fill(255,0,0);
        }
        else if(this.rand == 1)
        {
            fill(0,255,0);
        }
        else if(this.rand == 2)
        {
            fill(0,0,255);
        }
        else if(this.rand == 3)
        {
            fill(255,255,0);
        }
        else if(this.rand == 4)
        {
            fill(128,0,128);
        }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        noStroke();
        circle(this.position.x,this.position.y,CELL_SIZE);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
}



// ################################################################
// # ループ クラス
// ################################################################
class Game
{
    

    constructor()
    { 
        this.puyo = new Puyo();
        this.control = new Control();
    }

    Update()
    {
        this.puyo.setPosition(this.control.getPosition());
    }

    Renderer()
    {
        this.puyo.Renderer();
        //this.puyo.Renderer();
        //fill(color(0,255,0,255));
        //noStroke();
        //circle(this.position.x,this.position.y,CELL_SIZE);
    }
    

}
```

###### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=ja>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>puyopuyo</title>
        <body>   
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

            <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.6/p5.js"></script>
            
            <script src=../p5/p5.js></script>

            <!-- ユーティリティ -->
            <script src=../Utility/Math.js></script>
            <script src=../Utility/Vector.js></script>
            <script src=../Utility/Collision.js></script>
            
            <!-- ゲームループ -->
            <script src="Script/Game.js"></script>        

            <script src=Script/Main.js></script>
            
        </body>

    </head>
    
</html>
```

###### Main.js

```
let game;

// 初期化
function setup()
{
    createCanvas(640,480);
    
    game = new Game();
}



// 描画
function draw()
{
    background(127);        //背景色

    game.Update();
    game.Renderer();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

参照している Issue での説明を見る限り、`circle()` をサポートするのは **v0.7.3** 以降のようですが、あなたのコードでは v0.5.6 が指定されています。まずはこの部分を確認してみてください。